# Is 'Key' a reserved key word in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Today I was running one query where I wanted to get the key(column in the table) having sc_ticket name in it. So I tried to run this query.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Key]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties]
  where key like %sc_ticket%
```

It gave me an error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.

Comment: [KEY is a reserved SQL Server keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Don't name your database objects using `KEY`; use some other name.

Comment: Why not try with `[ ]`? I mean `[key]`.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use keyword as a object name, enclose it with `[]`. So for your this line `where key like %sc_ticket%` . Change to `[Key]`

Comment: @KrishnaGupta then please accept my answer. :)

Comment: Anyway this is a bad design, because then you'll need to use those brackets everywhere in your code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Go tell that to MIcrosoft, [they don't seem to have worked that out yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value)

Comment: Can't help it's in the system framework(Sitecore CMS) @astentx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a reserved SQL keyword and Value also. You should rename it. If you can't do it, use bracket in the where clause such as you do in the select
By the way, does your column name is Key or key?

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Key]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties]
  where [Key] like %sc_ticket%
```

Answer (score 4):

Because **KEY** is reserved keyword, try query like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Key]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties]
  where [Key] like %sc_ticket%
```

Switching `Key` to `[Key]`.

And **don't use keyword for naming columns!**

Comment: The correct solution is given here:  Don't use keywords as column names.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

`Key` is a reserved keyword in MSSQL.

See their list of reserved keywords here, in their [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

### Is there anyway to get around this issue?

Yes. You can wrap the word `key` in square brackets, like so: `[key]`

The query then becomes:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Key]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties]
  where [Key] like %sc_ticket%
```